# checkValidity() on part of a form?

Tags: html, validation

Is there a way to have `checkValidity()` only work on part of the form? For instance, checking validity on a `keyUp` event? Or is it strictly for complete form submission?

If it doesn't work that way, is there any third party plugin that works as a shim for these kinds of cases?

I haven't been able to find too much about `checkValidity()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to attach a keylistener to call the `checkValidity()` function, according to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

```
<input type="text" pattern="...stuff here..." onkeyup="alert(this.checkValidity());">
```

An example that will only match lower case letters and will alert the current validation status can be seen at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUd2j/).

Comment: In this case `this` is referring to the `input` field, not the entire form, correct?

Comment: Yes.  I posted a jsFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, though it would be a bit more complicated.  Can you explain what you're looking to do better?  I would make a function that gets the elements you want to validate and then validate each of them onkeyup.

Comment: You could also use `onBlur="alert(this.checkValidity());"`